# Fn function terminates before timeout

Tags: fn

I have set the timeout in func.yaml to 300 seconds (5 minutes) but the function only runs for 2 minutes and then terminates with error code 502.

```
Error invoking function. status: 502 message: error receiving function response
```

There is a github issue that discusses this problem:
https://github.com/fnproject/fn/issues/723

How do I resolve this problem?

**Edit:**

As an example, I created a nodejs function which should respond after 270 seconds but doesn't due to early timeout.

```
fdk.handle(function(input){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>resolve("Hello"),270000);
    });
})
```

Comment: What is error code 502? What response does your function generate? Show us your code.

Comment: It arises when the server is waiting for function response and doesn't get it in time. When I calculate the function time (using time utility e.g. time fn invoke...), it always terminates at 2m0.751s as apparently it is the actual function timeout.